# AppCenter is showing non-existing updates badge counter

Tags: updates, release-hera, appcenter, notifications, notification-badge

Since yesterday, one update is always showing, but no update is actually there. I don't have any PPA installed, everything has been installed trough AppCenter. I tried to update everything through Terminal all, is showing as up to date.

I am on an XPS 9550 with Hera 5.1.2.

[image]

Comment: This is a known issue, see: https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/1136

Comment: I think it's different, I never had a 0 showing, there is a 1. And I just got it for the past 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resolved itself with today's updates.

I think it is tied to Flatpak updates though, AppCenter is behaving weirdly when those are involved: by clicking Update All AppCenter does not asks for the user password, then closes itself. On reopening, the remaining non-Flatpak updates are still to be done, and at this point AppCenter asks for your password and proceeds as normal, staying open after done.

This must have messed up the badge counter last time, maybe?