# AppCenter shows notifications for update, but none are available

Tags: updates, release-hera

[image: AppCenter update]

I keep getting notifications from AppCenter saying there is 1 update available, but when I go into AppCenter there aren't actually any updates I can get. If I close AppCenter, I just get a notification again a few minutes later saying there is an update available.

I've tried `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade`, & `sudo apt dist-upgrade` from the terminal and none have made it stop or go away.

At one point there actually was an update available, so AppCenter notification said there were 2 updates available. After updating, it went back to saying 1 update available again.

Please help, this is getting very annoying.

Comment: Had the same issue, https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/25011/appcentre-updates-issue-hera?noredirect=1#comment26264_25011, and flatpak update fixed it for me too.

Answer (score 3):

```
flatpak update
```

fixed it for me as well

Answer (score 0):

Close AppCenter, open a terminal and try:

> sudo apt --fix-broken install

Let it work and now run

> sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

After this, sometimes you need to reboot for Appcenter to stop notifying (haven't tried log off/logon though)

-Aldo

Comment: Thanks, but the issues persists after trying this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but just went away by itself, check my thread.

[AppCenter is showing non-existing updates badge counter](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/22840/appcenter-is-showing-non-existing-updates-badge-counter/22854#22854)

Comment: Thanks, it did go away after a few days, with some more updates. It then kinda came back, but seemed to have something to do with flatpak updates as was mentioned in the thread you linked. It has since gone away again.

Answer (score 0):

I just run

```
$ flatpak update
```

without su permission

and the annoying red dot is no more.

Answer (score 0):

I tried command line with no luck then I ran Gnome software updater and it found openh264 from flathub to update, so I assume Med Fadil's solution is another way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Tried > flatpak update and this is what I got:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.
AppCentre is showing 2 apps for update.

Running flatpak twice. Once as sudo once as a user.
greg@Elementary-OS:~$ sudo flatpak update
[sudo] password for greg:
Looking for updates…

```
    ID                                Branch          Op          Remote             Download
```

1. [✓] org.gnome.Evince.Locale           stable          u           appcenter          1.1 kB / 1.5 MB
2. [✓] org.gnome.Evince                  stable          u           appcenter          1.7 MB / 11.0 MB

Updates complete.
greg@Elementary-OS:~$ sudo flatpak update
Looking for updates…
Nothing to do.
greg@Elementary-OS:~$ flatpak update
Looking for updates…

```
    ID                                             Branch                 Op            Remote             Download
```

1. [✓] org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default            23.08                  u             flathub            56.5 MB / 162.2 MB
2. [✓] org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default            23.08-extra            u             flathub            17.7 MB / 162.2 MB

Updates complete.
greg@Elementary-OS:~$
greg@Elementary-OS:~$ flatpak update
Looking for updates…
Nothing to do.
greg@Elementary-OS:~$