# AppCentre Updates Issue Hera

Tags: release-hera, appcenter, flatpak

Since I installed Gimp 2.10.20 via Flatpack a few days ago, my AppCenter is constantly telling me I have updates, but when I open up the AppCenter and go to Installed, there are no updates showing (see attached image), I've even done sudo apt update followed by sudo apt full-upgrade and it says All packages are up-to-date. My question is, are there updates or is this a quirk of AppCenter and Flatpacks? [image: AppCenter]

Comment: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/23894/appcenter-shows-notifications-for-update-but-none-are-available

Comment: @riffer - Cheers mate, I had no idea about flatpak update. Fixed it for me.