New EOS 8 user. Some apps fail to update in app store
New user here. I am familliar with other Linux OSs and this one is different for me. I had read through the forums and tried to update and upgrade with sudo apt upgrade and other commands. I have a runtime update that gives me a "Aborted due to failure (While trying to apply extra data: apply_extra script failed, exit status 256)" Is there anywhere to find what this error is? Thanks for the help.

Well apprenetly there is ZERO support for any issues in EOS. The App Center seems to have been having the same issue since OS5 with no fix. Sadly, as much as I like most of this OS, I can't stay. Too many problems and no support at all.

Someone gave me this tip on the discord channel, seems to have worked!

Run flatpak update in terminal to fix this. This is an upstream ubuntu error, not an eOS error
Ubuntu 24.04 introduced an issue with running extra_scripts during a
flatpak install that the command above fixes; where appcenter can't
yet (it's a pretty new bug).


Seems to have been an issue for a while: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/23894/appcenter-shows-notifications-for-update-but-none-are-available/24989#24989
